# Why is ElementRef to Canvas not working here?

Tags: angular, viewchild

I try to load an image into a canvas.

**In the template**

```
<canvas #myca id="mycanvas" style="width: 600px; height; 600px; border: 2px red solid;" (mousedown)="mdown ($event)"></canvas>
```

**In the component**

```
@ViewChild('myca', {static: false}) myca: ElementRef <HTMLCanvasElement>;

ngOnInit ()
{
    // ctx by id works!
    //var ctx = (<HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('mycanvas')).getContext('2d'); 

    // ctx by ElementRef fails!
    var ctx = this.myca.nativeElement.getContext('2d'); 

    var img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = "http://any_img_you_want.jpg";

    img1.onload = function () 
    {
        ctx.drawImage (img1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

If I get the ctx by the id it works. If I do it by the ElementRef it fails.
Whats the problem here?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? What happens exactly?

Comment: The code looks fine to me so a bit bizarre. Could you make a minimal stackblitz to help investigate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason.

In newer Angular versions the ViewChild Decorator needs 2nd parameter.
With only one I would get a typescript error.

If I change the static flag from false to true it works.

No special casting is needed.

```
@ViewChild('myca', {static: true}) myca: ElementRef;

...

var ctx = this.myca.nativeElement.getContext ("2d");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's problem of casting. Below code should work:

```
@ViewChild('myca') myca: ElementRef;

ngOnInit () {

    const ctx = (<HTMLCanvasElement>this.myca.nativeElement).getContext('2d');

    var img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = "http://any_img_you_want.jpg";

    img1.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage (img1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the code shown in the question, the element type is already specified in the declaration: `myca: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>`.