# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined in Ionic 5 and chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js, ionic5

I want to draw a barchart in my ionic 5 app. I use the code as below. But Always get an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement'` when I press the button `drawDaysSummary()`

I found the error happens when use `*ngIf` (`<ion-card *ngIf="drawDay == true">`). If use `<ion-card>` instead, the chart drawing works well.

I search the solution whole day but could not solve the problem. Could you please help?

home.html

```html
     <ion-content> 
      <ion-button expand="full" (click)="drawDaysSummary();" > Draw</ion-button>

      <ion-card *ngIf="drawDay == true">
        <ion-card-header>
          Bar Chart
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
          <canvas #barCanvas ></canvas>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
     </ion-content>
```

home.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, NgZone, ElementRef  } from '@angular/core';
    import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
    
    export class ItemHistoryPage implements OnInit {
      private barChart: Chart;
      @ViewChild('barCanvas', {static: true}) barCanvas: ElementRef;
    
      constructor(){
      }
    
      drawDaysSummary(){
        this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
    
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          }
    
        });
      }
```

my angular version information are:

```json
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.0.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",

    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.1.1",
```

Comment: which version of angular you are using ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727572/why-is-elementref-to-canvas-not-working-here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437850/9406763

Checkout these two answer might help.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Thanks. I add more information into my question

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper recreation on StackBlitz, it's hard to debug. But it does appear that the `drawDay` variable that you reference in your template doesn't exist in your TypeScript file.

Similarly, when toggling a conditionally rendered element like that the DOM actually has to play catch up before the element that you're referencing with your `@ViewChild` annotation is available. Typically, you can get around this by wrapping your code in a `setTimeout()` as that will push the code to the back of the event queue (which means the browser will render the content first and then execute the code).